# Chrome API download doesn't download a file, nor show in history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use [downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download) to download a file from a URL:

```
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: request.url,
                saveAs: true,
            }, function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    chrome.downloads.show(res);
                }
            );
```

It should download a file from the given url `request.url` (which I have confirmed is correct). When I call the download, it prints a downloadId and nothing else, it doesn't show up on download history nor in my downloads folder. It might be because I'm using a background worker?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome.